# document.ready image replace and performance

Tags: jquery, image, performance, dom, replace

I've created a jquery script, that replaces the source of specific images on document.ready, with a lightweight version of this image.

I know that document.ready is executed when the DOM is ready, meaning that the image request is already given to the user.

But also, not all images may have been loaded when document.ready is executed.

So would this give some performance benefits?

If i replace all these specific big images, with light weight versions of the images on document.ready?

I guess if the user has not yet downloaded all these big images, then the browser would just stop on replace and start downloading the lightweight versions?

Can someone explain this? This may sound a little strange, but i would like to know the best possible way to do this, when you don't have the possibility to change this server side.

Comment: Show us your code! A [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be great!

Comment: I think you can just put the url of the lightweight image in a data attribute on the `img` tag itself and not have any src on load, then use js to load the images using the data attributes. If you ant, you can even use div tags with data attributes then just replace them with `img` tags. There is no need to do this for all images, maybe just the bigger ones